# BindAsEventListener not returning Observe element in Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
    var Generic_Large_Blue = new Element('div', { 'id': 'divZoltarSubmit_', 'class': 'Generic_Large_Blue Blue_' + placeholder });
    var Generic_Large_Blue_Left = new Element('div', { 'class': 'Generic_Large_Blue_Left' });
    var Generic_Large_Blue_Middle = new Element('div', { 'class': 'Generic_Large_Blue_Middle' });
    var Generic_Large_Blue_Span = new Element('span').update("Submit");
    var Generic_Large_Blue_Right = new Element('div', { 'class': 'Generic_Large_Blue_Right' });

    //event on submit Click

    Event.observe(Generic_Large_Blue, 'click', function(event) {
        moZoltarCurrent.evt_ZoltarOnSubmit.bindAsEventListener(this,Item_TextArea, PriceInBox,event);            
    });

//this function is called when the submit button is clicked
evt_ZoltarOnSubmit: function(e) {

    var sourceElement = Event.element(e);
    var args = $A(arguments);
}
```

I have Click event on `Generic_Large_Blue` but Source Element Returned as  `Generic_Large_Blue_Left`,`Generic_Large_Blue_Middle`, `Generic_Large_Blue_Right`.

Depeding on Click postion Its not returning Observe Element

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the example for `bindAsEventListener` on its [documentation page](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/function/prototype/bindaseventlistener/). `bindAsEventListener` returns function, doesn't call function. Here is good code:

```
Event.observe(Generic_Large_Blue, 'click', moZoltarCurrent.evt_ZoltarOnSubmit.bindAsEventListener(this, Item_TextArea, PriceInBox));
```

PS: Next time check if your code is displayed correctly (you didn't specify what blocks are the code, so formatting fell apart).